# Antlr 4 C# grammar files

Tags: antlr, antlr4

We are looking for a code parser and Antlr seems to do the trick.  However, we cannot find the grammar files for C# 4.

Are there any Antlr 4 grammar files for C# 4.0 and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a C# runtime for ANTLR4: https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs
If you are looking for a grammar to parse C#, I'm afraid I haven't found one yet.